# Change date when next recurring local notification will trigger for ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I am using this plugin (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) for local notifications on Ionic. I want to be able set custom times for recurring notifications. Cordova Local Notification object has an "every" attribute but I want to be to change what time the notification is triggered each time it is triggered instead of just relying on what is set on the "every" attribute. I have tried updating the notification on trigger to reset the "at" attribute but it does not work

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger',
                function (event, notification, state) {
                    var newDate = getNewDate();
                    $cordovaLocalNotification.update({
                        id: notification.id,
                        at: newDate,
                        every: "year",
                        message: notification.message,
                        title: notification.title,
                        data: notification.data
                    });
                });
```

I tried not using the every "attribute" so that it uses the default value of 0 which means that the notification triggers just once and then I can schedule a new one with the date I want but on both iOS and Android emulators, the notifications are coming persistently. It seems there is a problem when "every" has a value of 0